# Why am I getting a blank element with this code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an script that starts with two arrays, one with data and one without. The one without is supposed to be an array of 'used' elements.

I have a 'start' button that prints the array elements as li elements to the respective ul list.

I also have a 'move' button that removes a random element, and appends it to the 'used' array then reprints the lists to reflect the changes. If the first list is empty, it loops through the second and pushes it back into the first.

The problem I'm having is, at random, I'm getting what seems to be an empty element and it gets printed to either array. I also am not getting the expected result when pressing the 'start' button to 'reset' everything. I've tried all I can think of and I can't get it working the way I want it to.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [];

const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
const moveBtn = document.getElementById('moveBtn');

const listOne = document.getElementById('listOne');
const listTwo = document.getElementById('listTwo');

const buildList = (arr, list) => {
    // Remove elements to start fresh
    while(list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
    // Build List
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = arr[i];
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
};

startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    buildList(arr1, listOne);
    buildList(arr2, listTwo);
});

moveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(arr1.length === 0) {
        for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            arr1.push(arr2.splice(arr2[i], 1));
        }
    } else {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);
        arr2.push(arr1.splice(randomIndex, 1));
        for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i ++) {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = arr2[i];
            listTwo.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
    
    buildList(arr1, listOne);
    buildList(arr2, listTwo);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Array Test</h1>

    <button id="startBtn">Start</button>

    <button id="moveBtn">Move</button>

    <br>

    <ul id="listOne"></ul>
    
    <ul id="listTwo"></ul>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add this as a code snippet to your question, which viewers can run.

Answer (score 1):

The following code may be fixed, but when the first item is pushed back to the first array, the first array length is not 0 anymore, so you will get stuck there pushing back and forward. You didn't specify your intended behaviour after that. However, if you wanted to loop each array until empty alternately, it would be very easy to do using a flag to switch source/target arrays every time that current source length is 0.

You also had and extra for loop to insert the new li element in the list, but it was unnecessary because lists manipulation is already done by your buildList function.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [];

const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
const moveBtn = document.getElementById('moveBtn');

const listOne = document.getElementById('listOne');
const listTwo = document.getElementById('listTwo');

const buildList = (arr, list) => {
    // Remove elements to start fresh
    while(list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
    // Build List
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = arr[i];
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
};

startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    buildList(arr1, listOne);
    buildList(arr2, listTwo);
});

moveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let randomIndex;
    
    if (arr1.length) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);
        (arr2).push(arr1.splice(randomIndex, 1));
    } else {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr2.length);
        (arr1).push(arr2.splice(randomIndex, 1));
    }
    
    buildList(arr1, listOne);
    buildList(arr2, listTwo);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Array Test</h1>

    <button id="startBtn">Start</button>

    <button id="moveBtn">Move</button>

    <br>

    <ul id="listOne"></ul>
    
    <ul id="listTwo"></ul>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For start button to work you need to reset arr1 and arr2

```
startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    arr2 = [];

    buildList(arr1, listOne);
    buildList(arr2, listTwo);
});
```

As for your blank entries, this is caused by splicing the array while looping forward

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    arr1.push(arr2.splice(arr2[i], 1));
}
```

If you loop backward instead like this it will work

```
for(let i = arr2.length; i > 0 ; i--) {
    arr1.push(arr2.splice(arr2[i], 1));
}
```

Alternatively you could do this instead

```
arr1 = arr2;
arr2 = [];
```